# How to access href of a tag in node.js

Tags: html, node.js, xpath

I have this function

```
function getxPath(data, path) {
  console.log("HEREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
  console.log(path);
  //console.log(data);
  try {
    let root = new dom().parseFromString(data);
    console.log(root);
    let results = xpath.select(path, root);
    console.log(results);
    if (results.length > 0) {
      let _results = [];
      for (let r of results) {
        _results.push(r.textContent);
      }
      return _results;
    }
  } catch (exc) {
    console.log(exc);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Path is : `//a[@class='classifiedTitle']/@href`

I am trying to get links of all the ads on this page:

```
https://www.sahibinden.com/en/cars/used?date=1day&a5_min=2005&a5_max=2020
```

But it returns null even though the xpath seems correct.

Edit:
I used full xpath and it gave me the title of a. But when I use even @href it doesnt give

Edit:
I am able to get links using this xpath :

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/form/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr//a[1]/@href
```

Comment: I guess you use node.js to get the source of the page in question for processing on your server. The ads are most likely added dynamically after page load and are not included in the HTML source you retrieved.

Comment: @wp78de I do have these in there  <a class=" classifiedTitle"
    title="2015 MODEL 45 BİN KM ORJİNAL 50.YEARS EDITION ÖZEL SERİ"
    href="/listing/vasita-otomobil-ford-2015-model-45-bin-km-orjinal-50.years-edition-ozel-seri-832713249/detail">